# pythonでwavファイルを読み込みたいです。

Tags: python, scipy

pythonでwavファイルを読み込みたいです。

```
>>> import spicy
>>> from scipy import io
>>> from scipy.io import wavfile
>>> sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read("test.wav")
ValueError: Not a WAV file.（実際にはもっといろいろと表示されています）
```

上記のようにしてwavファイルを読み込みたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
ファイルの種類はWAVE オーディオと表示されています。
何がいけないのでしょうか？macを使っているのですが、macではwavをうまく処理できないのでしょうか？

また上記の話は実践機械学習システムの９章に基づいて行っているのですが、上記の最後の部分が

```
>>> sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wave_filename)
```

となっていて、フォルダ内のデータをすべて読み込んでいるように書かれているのですが
それは可能ですか？
音楽データを一つ一つではなくまとめて読み込む方法があれば知りたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11161066831 マルチポスト

Comment: 既に知恵袋の方で解決されているようですね。この投稿を見た人が未解決と勘違いしないように、ご自身で解決策を回答として投稿するなり、質問を削除するなり、何かしら対応をしていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2):

`Not a WAV file`
というエラーメッセージの通り、WAVファイルではないということだと思います。
このファイルをプレーヤー等で再生できるか試しましたか？